# how to retrieve database columns when using eloquent with vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I am trying to fetch data from database using AXIOS get request.i have 2 models (Content and Word)having many to many relationships. in my controller I am trying this :

```
public function fetchCourses(){
    $dayOne = Content::where(['course_id'=>'1','day_id'=>'1'])->first();
    return $dayOne;
}
```

in vue i am trying like this :

```
axios.get('/getCourse').then((response)=>{
    //console.log(response.data);
    this.content = response.data;
})
```

Then in the component :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" :src="content.video_clip"  frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

video_clip is one of the column names in my Contents table.

Now I want to fetch not only contents but words also from Word Model. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Yes. Will be glad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the `words` relationship (assuming that's the name):

```
$dayOne = Content::where(['course_id'=>'1','day_id'=>'1'])->with('words')->first();
```

Then you can access the words in your frontend:

```
this.content.words
```